# How Do I Fix an Access Forbidden Issue

Tags: image, pyrocms

I am using PyroCMS to develop a site where I need to access some image files.  When I click on the a link I get

"Access Forbidden -You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server."

Ok - so I'm on using windows on localhost, so I go to the top level folder for the images and change the security to allow all. Still no good. OK, so I try to access the images directly through the browser with the direct url. It lets me in and I see the image.

So what gives ?? Is there something inside Apache I need to change ?? Don't think so or else it would not let me in at all, right ?

Any ideas ?

Many thanks !!

and yes I will select a "best answer"

Comment: I forgot to mention that I can access the pictures fine when the tags are NOT wrapped in an <a class="gallery" href="Blah">

However, the class "gallery" invokes a simple ColorBox js lightbox function.

Comment: Much easier for people to help with this one, I suspect, if you upload an actual example we can all view... however it sounds as though your link might going to a different URL than the images.  Doesn't sound like a PyroCMS issue to me.  That particular error is sometimes caused by having an 'Order deny,allow, Deny from all' left in your Apache config - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_access.html#order